# Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read (f7.0)

Tags: fortran, runtime-error

I am trying to execute a Fortran code and I get the following error:

> At line 215 of file prepmegan4cmaq_grwform.f90
> Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read

And this is how the line 215 of my .f90 file looks like:

```
read(shrubfillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
```

I do not have any experience with Fortran coding, can someone please tell me what it means and how I can fix this problem.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. It is very important to get all the important information. The error message speaks about a floating point value and the statement you show is a read statement from some file (possible internal one). It is extremely important to show more code. All symbols appearing in your line should be declared. You should show what `shrubfillvalue` is and what `missing_value` is and if possible what are their values or what kind of values is being read from an external file (if applicable). See also [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you that the text it tried to read did not meet the rules for a numeric value. The code itself is fine, the error is in the input (which you did not show).

The F7.0 format will accept seven characters that are valid as a number, for example: -1234.5, 2478bbb, 3.15E24, etc. (where "b" means blank). So, look at the input file and see what is in that line.

It is possible that the program is reading the wrong line from the file after having read an incorrect number of lines previously.

Comment: Dear Steve, Thank you for your complete instructions. My input file is a large NetCDF file (1.8Gb) containing percents. I have four of these files which this program needs to read. It reads the first file without problem but for the second file it does not work. I cannot use ncdump on the file because it says it's an "Unknown file format". When I open the file with python it seems like it holds integer values. Isn't there a more flexible way for the program to read numbers so I can use?

Comment: Can you show an example line of the file? I assume all lines have the same layout.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been running the latest version of MEGANv3.2, and found this to be an issue with reading missing_value attribute in 3 out of 4 of the input files provided by the MEGAN team.

Since all of the missing_value attributes are the same between the four different files (i.e., -128), a very quick work around is to simply change the prepmegan4cmaq_grwform.f90 code to read only the treefillvalue for each of the four datasets:

```
!-----read growth form----------------------------------------------
  scale_factor  = 1.
  inpname       = trim(treefilename)
  varname       = trim(treevarname)
  !missing_value = -1.
  read(treefillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  CALL  megan2_bioemiss
  inpname       = trim(shrubfilename)
  varname       = trim(shrubvarname)
!      read(shrubfillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  read(treefillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  CALL  megan2_bioemiss
  inpname       = trim(cropfilename)
  varname       = trim(cropvarname)
!      read(cropfillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  read(treefillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  CALL  megan2_bioemiss
  inpname       = trim(grassfilename)
  varname       = trim(grassvarname)
!      read(grassfillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  read(treefillvalue,"(f7.0)") missing_value
  CALL  megan2_bioemiss

!     endif
```

And then simply recompile the prepmegan4cmaq_grwform.f90 code.  Hope this helps.